# What's the effect of buffer

Tags: http, io, buffer

I found lots of places use buffer, such as IO operation, transfer data through network, I couldn't understand clearly about the effect of buffer and how to determine the size of buffer?

Comment: Have you read the Wikipedia article? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_buffer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buffers are most often used in cases where the I/O operation is dealing with large amounts of data or when there needs to be very low latency in the operations.  Most I/O implementations provide buffer defaults, but they also make it easy to override the defaults and in some cases even replace the buffering infrastructure so that the developer has the option to customize things in more extreme cases.

If you are not dealing with very large amounts of data or are not dealing with very high numbers of users, then you can probably use the buffer defaults provided in most cases.